# Nunit TestCaseSource all must pass

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, sharpdevelop

Im using Nunit with sharpdevelop, ive made a testcasesource. It seems that as long as one passes, it goes green. I want the opposite, if even one fails, i want the test to fail. How can i accomplish this?

Current code

```
[Test,TestCaseSource("currencySource")]
public void CurrenciesDontMatch(CurrencyLookup argLookup){
    localCLookup.Add(new CurrencyLookup(){CurrencyID=1,ApproxConversion=(decimal)1.5,CurrencyName="RBY"});
    foriegnCLookup.Add(argLookup);
    CurrencyUpdater cUpdate= new CurrencyUpdater(localCLookup,foriegnCLookup);
    Assert.IsFalse(cUpdate.isUpdated());
}
```

Comment: NUnit should create a test for each item in the source, I'm wondering if there's something odd going on with a test runner. What are you using to run your tests?

Comment: Im just using sharpDevelops Nunit plugin. Its showing that certain tests are failing. But in the gui pane the test glows green.

Comment: As @ChrisMissal says, I also think this is an issue with sharpDevelops test runner. Try running your tests with an NUnit test runner (GUI or console) and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: SharpDevelop's NUnit test runner does not support TestCase or TestCaseSource currently.